# start-dfs.sh: command not found

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed hadoop 2.7.0. on Ubuntu 14.04. But the code `start-dfs.sh` is not working. when I run this code It returns `start-dfs.sh: command not found`. The `start-dfs.sh`, `start-all.sh` , `stop-dfs.sh` and `stop-all.sh` are in the **sbin** directory. I have installed and set the paths of **java** and **hadoop** correctly. The codes `hadoop version` and `ssh localhost` also working. what might be the problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Does the file `start-dfs.sh`exists in the directory `${HADOOP_HOME}/bin`? If not, please try to run commond **`sbin/start-dfs.sh`**.